# Ionic tabs loading automatically with out clicking

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have code page.html to create tabs

```
<ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab [root]="page1" [rootParams]="chatParams" tabTitle="Chat" tabIcon="chat"></ion-tab>
 </ion-tabs>
```

and in page.ts is like below

```
export class samplePage {
  page1: any = CarListPage;
  page2: any = CarListPage;
  page3: any = CarListPage;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public bookingService: BookingProvider,
  ) {
  }
```

when I open the page, the tab page is also displaying which is assigned in page.ts. Why it is displaying automatically without clicking that page could any please help me in this regard. It might be great help

Comment: so what behavior you want or expect? Tab pages is a type of UX where normally there is a default landing page out of available ones. If none is default - what you want it to display then?

Comment: When click on tab only i want to display page content

Comment: but what do you want to display if user is not clicking?

Comment: see i have page called bookings, in that page there is  tab . Before clicking tab i want to display bookings page content and after clicking i want display the tab page content